# Вывести массив из-под функции

Tags: jquery, массивы, json

Здравствуйте.

Возникла проблема. Есть код (уменьшил и убрал лишнее).

```
    var arr1 = '';

    $.ajax({
        'type': 'GET',
        'dataType': 'json',
        'url': '/output.php',
        'data': 'q=game',
        success: function (json) {

            if (json.result.length > 0) {
                var arr1 = [{
                    "title": "fhfhfhfhfh",
                    "type": "movie"
                }, {
                    "title": "hgfdhfhfd",
                    "type": "movie"
                }, {
                    "title": "dhgdfhgd",
                    "type": "movie"
                }, {
                    "title": "ddhfdhfh",
                    "type": "music"
                }, {
                    "title": "dhfhfdhf",
                    "type": "video"
                }];
                var arr2 = [];

                $.merge(arr1, arr2);
            }
        },
        error: function () {
            alert("Error load");
        }
$('body').html('lenght: ' + arr1.length);
```

В идее - сделать несколько вызовов ajax и собрать в один массив - и вывод. (Возможно, вы скажете, что глупо вызывать несколько результатов и собирать в один массив, объясню, почему так делаю. Сам скрипт (php) берет с разных сайтов инфу и переводит в один массив и выводит в json формате, но он долго работает (думал сделать кеширование, записывать в базу и выводить, но тут свои грабли: может инфа устареть, да и для каждого запроса запись в базу может еще больше скрипт тупить). Поэтому я делаю для каждого сайта отдельный вызов и потом постепенно догружаю в общий список. Написаный способ - не есть гениальный, поэтому принимаю критику.

Comment: То что костыль на костыле я понял, а проблема то в чем? конкретно напишите что вы хотите увидеть

Comment: поправил.
Немогу вывести массив который обьеденил. Проблема с переменной, с под функции "не выходит"

Answer (score 4):

Лично я, по делу, не понял практически ничего. И почему не сделать **сразу** несколько запросов? Ну да не суть, переменная arr1 не изменяется т.к. вы не переопределяете ее значение, вместо этого создаете локальную для функции переменную использовав *var*. Вообщем:

```
var arr1 = [{ ... }]; // не правильно
    arr1 = [{ ... }]; // правильно
```

К тому-же:

```
$('body').html('lenght: ' + arr1.length);
```

Всегда будет выводить 0 т.к. этот код выполняется до того, как переменная arr1 переопределена, соотвтетсвенно что-бы увидеть нужный результат эту строчку кода нужно поместить в обработчик ответа сервера.

Comment: Не работает( Уже сколько вариантов перепробовал(

    arr1 = [];
    $.ajax({
        success: function (json) {

            if (json.result.length > 0) {

                arr2 = [{
                    "title": "ddhfdhfh",
                    "type": "music"
                }, {
                    "title": "dhfhfdhf",
                    "type": "video"
                }];
                $.merge(arr1, arr2);

            }
        },
        error: function () {
            alert("Error load");
        }
    });
    $('body').html('lenght: ' + arr2.length);

Comment: Вам бы JS подучить сначала -_-

Comment: Я в juqery новичек.

Comment: Суть я вам написал, то, что вы не знаете языка - проблема не моя. 

Если хотите - ждите, быть может кто-то сделает вам медвежью услугу и напишет код целяком.

Comment: Я наверное неправильно написал в чем проблема. Я код не написал для того чтобы мне написали как правильно а чтобы увидеть общую картину. Мне бы только подсказать как вынести результат с $.ajax() - success.
Я понимаю что каждый раз писать что неполучаеться неправильно.
С jquery пару дней только работаю, с php немножко путаю.

Comment: вынести результат с $.ajax() - success

Это не php, событийное программирование не является линейным, соответственно что-то типа:

    var data = getAjax();

Сделать не получиться (вернее получиться с использованием синхронного ajax'a, но это, мягко говоря, не есть хорошо).

Вообщем вердикт -> матчасть, причем начиная с хелло ворлдов

Answer (score 0):

jquery тут не причем, вам нужно разобраться с асинхронностью в js.
Внимательно по порядку:

```
var arr1 = []; // 1

$.ajax({ // 2 отправляется запрос на сервер
    'type': 'GET',
    'dataType': 'json',
    'url': '/output.php',
    'data': 'q=game',
    success: function (json) { // 4 в случае успешного запроса

        if (json.result.length > 0) {
            var arr2 = [{
                "title": "fhfhfhfhfh",
            ...
                 "type": "video"
            }];

            $.merge(arr1, arr2);

            $('body').html('lenght: ' + arr1.length); // 5 нужный момент !!!
        }
    },
    error: function () { // 4 в случае неудачного запроса
        alert("Error load");
    }
});

$('body').html('lenght: ' + arr1.length); // 3 выводим длину
```